# Caliburn.Micro TreeView add a static element

Tags: wpf, treeview, caliburn.micro

I have a working TreeView

```
                        <TreeView x:Name="TVAccess" ItemsSource="{Binding AccessLevel}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <!--<CheckBox Checked="{Binding Checked}"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
```

It is bind to AccessLevel object defined like this

```
public BindableCollection<UserLibrary.DataAccess.TextHelper.TreeViewItem> AccessLevel { get; set; }
```

This works well
The result is this

[image]

I would like to add a fixed first level named "Access Right", how can I do that?

EDIT 1

The structure I would like is this:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

### Edit 2 - The TreeViewItem class

```
public class TreeViewItem
{
    public string Text { get;  set; }
    public bool Checked { get;  set; }
}
```

### Edit 3 - Modify the TreeViewItem Class

So if I mofify my call like this, now the problem is to bind it to the TreeView

```
    public class TreeViewItem
{
    public string Text { get;  set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> SubTreeViewItem { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `TreeViewItem` to the source collection at index `0`.

```
AccessLevel.Insert(0, new UserLibrary.DataAccess.TextHelper.TreeViewItem() { Text = "Access Right" } );
```

Or set the `ItemsSource` property to a `CompositeCollection` and define the fixed item in the XAML markup:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TVAccess" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="source" Source="{Binding AccessLevel}" />
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <local:TreeViewItem Text="Access Right" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource source}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </TreeView.ItemsSource>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<CheckBox Checked="{Binding Checked}"/>-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact your solution add correctly my text. But I would like to have all my "Level O to 29" UNDER the "Access Level" text. Hope I'm clear

Comment: @StéphanF: Then you should simply add all the items to the `Items` property (or whatever you call it) of the additional `TreeViewItem` that you create in your view model. Please post the defintion of your class if you need any further help.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have added an "Edit 2" with the definition of the TreeViewItem class

Comment: @StéphanF: Your `TreeViewItem` class isn't hierarchical. You should add an `IEnumerable<TreeViewItem>` property to it.

Comment: Yes I no, but fist I didin't want to do it for 2 reason. First, I have only one first level item. And second, I don't kwow how to bind a hierarchical class to a TreeView using Caliburn.Micro

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you have or or many root level elements. A root element still needs to have children for you to be able expand it. Your second question doesn't make much sense. What do you mean? Don't you know how to bind? The fact that you are using Caliburn.Micro doesn't change the way the `TreeView` control works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I changed my TreeViewITem to have an IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> property. For my second question, do I need to do a specific binding in the xaml to bind to this IEnumerable<TreeViewItem>?

Comment: @StéphanF: You bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to the `IEnumerable<TreeViewItem>` source property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212431/discussion-between-stephan-f-and-mm8).